# Pocketsphinx Input overrun, read calls are too rare

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, buildroot, pocketsphinx

I try to install Pocketsphinx on a speaker which works with Buildroot. Before testing it on the speaker, I tried Pocketsphinx on my Raspberry-pi3.
The problem is that I have different results on both devices, despite them having approximately the same hardware performance.

When I try to decode a wav file, I have this result on both devices (both accuracy and time are similar):

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -infile /mnt/usb/file-16000.wav -dict /mnt/usb/sphinx-
french/fr.dict -lm /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/fr-small.lm.bin -hmm /mnt/usb/sphinx-f
rench/cmusphinx-fr-5.2
INFO: pocketsphinx.c(152): Parsed model-specific feature parameters from /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/feat.params
Current configuration:
[NAME]                  [DEFLT]         [VALUE]
-agc                    none            none
-agcthresh              2.0             2.000000e+00
-allphone
-allphone_ci            no              no
-alpha                  0.97            9.700000e-01
-ascale                 20.0            2.000000e+01
-aw                     1               1
-backtrace              no              no
-beam                   1e-48           1.000000e-48
-bestpath               yes             yes
-bestpathlw             9.5             9.500000e+00
-ceplen                 13              13
-cmn                    current         current
-cmninit                8.0             8.0
-compallsen             no              no
-debug                                  0
-dict                                   /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/fr.dict
-dictcase               no              no
-dither                 no              no
-doublebw               no              no
-ds                     1               1
-fdict
-feat                   1s_c_d_dd       1s_c_d_dd
-featparams
-fillprob               1e-8            1.000000e-08
-frate                  100             100
-fsg
-fsgusealtpron          yes             yes
-fsgusefiller           yes             yes
-fwdflat                yes             yes
-fwdflatbeam            1e-64           1.000000e-64
-fwdflatefwid           4               4
-fwdflatlw              8.5             8.500000e+00
-fwdflatsfwin           25              25
-fwdflatwbeam           7e-29           7.000000e-29
-fwdtree                yes             yes
-hmm                                    /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2
-input_endian           little          little
-jsgf
-keyphrase
-kws
-kws_delay              10              10
-kws_plp                1e-1            1.000000e-01
-kws_threshold          1               1.000000e+00
-latsize                5000            5000
-lda
-ldadim                 0               0
-lifter                 0               22
-lm                                     /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/fr-small.lm.bin
-lmctl
-lmname
-logbase                1.0001          1.000100e+00
-logfn
-logspec                no              no
-lowerf                 133.33334       1.300000e+02
-lpbeam                 1e-40           1.000000e-40
-lponlybeam             7e-29           7.000000e-29
-lw                     6.5             6.500000e+00
-maxhmmpf               30000           30000
-maxwpf                 -1              -1
-mdef
-mean
-mfclogdir
-min_endfr              0               0
-mixw
-mixwfloor              0.0000001       1.000000e-07
-mllr
-mmap                   yes             yes
-ncep                   13              13
-nfft                   512             512
-nfilt                  40              25
-nwpen                  1.0             1.000000e+00
-pbeam                  1e-48           1.000000e-48
-pip                    1.0             1.000000e+00
-pl_beam                1e-10           1.000000e-10
-pl_pbeam               1e-10           1.000000e-10
-pl_pip                 1.0             1.000000e+00
-pl_weight              3.0             3.000000e+00
-pl_window              5               5
-rawlogdir
-remove_dc              no              no
-remove_noise           yes             yes
-remove_silence         yes             yes
-round_filters          yes             yes
-samprate               16000           1.600000e+04
-seed                   -1              -1
-sendump
-senlogdir
-senmgau
-silprob                0.005           5.000000e-03
-smoothspec             no              no
-svspec
-tmat
-tmatfloor              0.0001          1.000000e-04
-topn                   4               4
-topn_beam              0               0
-toprule
-transform              legacy          dct
-unit_area              yes             yes
-upperf                 6855.4976       6.800000e+03
-uw                     1.0             1.000000e+00
-vad_postspeech         50              50
-vad_prespeech          20              20
-vad_startspeech        10              10
-vad_threshold          2.0             2.000000e+00
-var
-varfloor               0.0001          1.000000e-04
-varnorm                no              no
-verbose                no              no
-warp_params
-warp_type              inverse_linear  inverse_linear
-wbeam                  7e-29           7.000000e-29
-wip                    0.65            6.500000e-01
-wlen                   0.025625        2.562500e-02

INFO: feat.c(715): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='current', VARNORM='no', AGC='none'
INFO: cmn.c(143): mean[0]= 12.00, mean[1..12]= 0.0
INFO: acmod.c(152): Reading linear feature transformation from /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/feature_transform
INFO: mdef.c(518): Reading model definition: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/mdef
INFO: bin_mdef.c(181): Allocating 101051 * 8 bytes (789 KiB) for CD tree
INFO: tmat.c(149): Reading HMM transition probability matrices: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/transition_matrices
INFO: acmod.c(113): Attempting to use PTM computation module
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/means
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  8x32
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/variances
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  8x32
INFO: ms_gauden.c(304): 0 variance values floored
INFO: ptm_mgau.c(804): Number of codebooks exceeds 256: 2108
INFO: acmod.c(115): Attempting to use semi-continuous computation module
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/means
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  8x32
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/variances
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  8x32
INFO: ms_gauden.c(304): 0 variance values floored
INFO: acmod.c(117): Falling back to general multi-stream GMM computation
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/means
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  8x32
INFO: ms_gauden.c(127): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/variances
INFO: ms_gauden.c(242): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size: 
INFO: ms_gauden.c(244):  8x32
INFO: ms_gauden.c(304): 0 variance values floored
INFO: ms_senone.c(149): Reading senone mixture weights: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/mixture_weights
INFO: ms_senone.c(200): Truncating senone logs3(pdf) values by 10 bits
INFO: ms_senone.c(207): Not transposing mixture weights in memory
INFO: ms_senone.c(268): Read mixture weights for 2108 senones: 1 features x 8 codewords
INFO: ms_senone.c(320): Mapping senones to individual codebooks
INFO: ms_mgau.c(144): The value of topn: 4
INFO: phone_loop_search.c(114): State beam -225 Phone exit beam -225 Insertion penalty 0
INFO: dict.c(320): Allocating 109102 * 20 bytes (2130 KiB) for word entries
INFO: dict.c(333): Reading main dictionary: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/fr.dict
INFO: dict.c(213): Dictionary size 105003, allocated 1018 KiB for strings, 1375 KiB for phones
INFO: dict.c(336): 105003 words read
INFO: dict.c(358): Reading filler dictionary: /mnt/usb/sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/noisedict
INFO: dict.c(213): Dictionary size 105006, allocated 0 KiB for strings, 0 KiB for phones
INFO: dict.c(361): 3 words read
INFO: dict2pid.c(396): Building PID tables for dictionary
INFO: dict2pid.c(406): Allocating 36^3 * 2 bytes (91 KiB) for word-initial triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(132): Allocated 15696 bytes (15 KiB) for word-final triphones
INFO: dict2pid.c(196): Allocated 15696 bytes (15 KiB) for single-phone word triphones
INFO: ngram_model_trie.c(347): Trying to read LM in trie binary format
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(74): Initializing search tree
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(101): 742 unique initial diphones
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(186): Creating search channels
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(323): Max nonroot chan increased to 122777
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(333): Created 733 root, 122649 non-root channels, 124 single-phone words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(157): fwdflat: min_ef_width = 4, max_sf_win = 25
INFO: continuous.c(307): pocketsphinx_continuous COMPILED ON: May 27 2019, AT: 10:26:52

INFO: ngram_search.c(459): Resized backpointer table to 10000 entries
INFO: ngram_search.c(467): Resized score stack to 200000 entries
INFO: ngram_search.c(459): Resized backpointer table to 20000 entries
INFO: cmn_prior.c(131): cmn_prior_update: from <  8.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 >
INFO: cmn_prior.c(149): cmn_prior_update: to   < 32.09  6.52  5.60  4.29 -3.16 -8.27 -12.06 10.93  2.41 -0.40 -8.79  0.44 -0.56 >
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1550):    14013 words recognized (74/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1552):   215554 senones evaluated (1134/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1556):  1691781 channels searched (8904/fr), 88058 1st, 244061 last
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1559):    25969 words for which last channels evaluated (136/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1561):   232530 candidate words for entering last phone (1223/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1564): fwdtree 7.54 CPU 3.968 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1567): fwdtree 7.54 wall 3.971 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(302): Utterance vocabulary contains 616 words
2019-05-28 12:25:39.086 [  3] E MessageRouter:sendFailed:reason=noActiveTransport
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(948):    10755 words recognized (57/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(950):   117062 senones evaluated (616/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(952):   610492 channels searched (3213/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(954):    60608 words searched (318/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(957):    31719 word transitions (166/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(960): fwdflat 2.83 CPU 1.491 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(963): fwdflat 2.84 wall 1.492 xRT
INFO: ngram_search.c(1197): </s> not found in last frame, using lin.188 instead
INFO: ngram_search.c(1250): lattice start node <s>.0 end node lin(2).106
INFO: ngram_search.c(1276): Eliminated 61 nodes before end node
INFO: ngram_search.c(1381): Lattice has 851 nodes, 10478 links
INFO: ps_lattice.c(1380): Bestpath score: -5096
INFO: ps_lattice.c(1384): Normalizer P(O) = alpha(lin(2):106:188) = -441437
INFO: ps_lattice.c(1441): Joint P(O,S) = -466741 P(S|O) = -25304
INFO: ngram_search.c(872): bestpath 0.34 CPU 0.182 xRT
INFO: ngram_search.c(875): bestpath 0.34 wall 0.182 xRT
l' effet lin
INFO: cmn_prior.c(131): cmn_prior_update: from < 32.09  6.52  5.60  4.29 -3.16 -8.27 -12.06 10.93  2.41 -0.40 -8.79  0.44 -0.56 >
INFO: cmn_prior.c(149): cmn_prior_update: to   < 34.37 10.57  2.93  6.10 -3.33 -8.18 -9.87  9.27  5.29 -1.59 -9.36 -0.16 -0.33 >
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1550):     8923 words recognized (47/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1552):   281781 senones evaluated (1483/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1556):  2204387 channels searched (11602/fr), 105569 1st, 153123 last
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1559):    19639 words for which last channels evaluated (103/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1561):   259693 candidate words for entering last phone (1366/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1564): fwdtree 12.02 CPU 6.328 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1567): fwdtree 12.04 wall 6.335 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(302): Utterance vocabulary contains 534 words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(948):     4119 words recognized (22/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(950):   125859 senones evaluated (662/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(952):   345149 channels searched (1816/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(954):    41363 words searched (217/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(957):    27086 word transitions (142/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(960): fwdflat 1.86 CPU 0.977 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(963): fwdflat 1.86 wall 0.978 xRT
INFO: ngram_search.c(1250): lattice start node <s>.0 end node </s>.132
INFO: ngram_search.c(1276): Eliminated 5 nodes before end node
INFO: ngram_search.c(1381): Lattice has 630 nodes, 4128 links
INFO: ps_lattice.c(1380): Bestpath score: -6334
INFO: ps_lattice.c(1384): Normalizer P(O) = alpha(</s>:132:188) = -475100
INFO: ps_lattice.c(1441): Joint P(O,S) = -491474 P(S|O) = -16374
INFO: ngram_search.c(872): bestpath 0.10 CPU 0.053 xRT
INFO: ngram_search.c(875): bestpath 0.10 wall 0.055 xRT
comme lui
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(429): TOTAL fwdtree 19.56 CPU 5.176 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(432): TOTAL fwdtree 19.58 wall 5.180 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(176): TOTAL fwdflat 4.69 CPU 1.240 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(179): TOTAL fwdflat 4.69 wall 1.242 xRT
INFO: ngram_search.c(303): TOTAL bestpath 0.44 CPU 0.117 xRT
INFO: ngram_search.c(306): TOTAL bestpath 0.45 wall 0.118 xRT
```

But when I try to use pocketsphinx to decode  my words from a mic,it works on raspberry but not on my speaker.

I have this feedback from my raspberry:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes -adcdev plug:pcm.mic -dict sphinx-french/fr.dict -hmm sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2 -lm sphinx-french/fr-small.lm.bin INFO: pocketsphinx.c(145): Parsed model-specific feature parameters from sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/feat.params Current configuration: [NAME]          [DEFLT]     [VALUE]
-agc            none        none
-agcthresh      2.0     2.000000e+00
-allphone               
-allphone_ci        no      no
-alpha          0.97        9.700000e-01
-ascale         20.0        2.000000e+01
-aw         1       1
-backtrace      no      no
-beam           1e-48       1.000000e-48
-bestpath       yes     yes
-bestpathlw     9.5     9.500000e+00
-ceplen         13      13
-cmn            current     current
-cmninit        8.0     8.0
-compallsen     no      no
-debug                  0
-dict                   sphinx-french/fr.dict
-dictcase       no      no
-dither         no      no
-doublebw       no      no
-ds         1       1
-fdict                  sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/noisedict
-feat           1s_c_d_dd   1s_c_d_dd
-featparams             sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/feat.params
-fillprob       1e-8        1.000000e-08
-frate          100     100
-fsg                    
-fsgusealtpron      yes     yes
-fsgusefiller       yes     yes
-fwdflat        yes     yes
-fwdflatbeam        1e-64       1.000000e-64
-fwdflatefwid       4       4
-fwdflatlw      8.5     8.500000e+00
-fwdflatsfwin       25      25
-fwdflatwbeam       7e-29       7.000000e-29
-fwdtree        yes     yes
-hmm                    sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2
-input_endian       little      little
-jsgf                   
-keyphrase              
-kws                    
-kws_delay      10      10
-kws_plp        1e-1        1.000000e-01
-kws_threshold      1       1.000000e+00
-latsize        5000        5000
-lda                    sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/feature_transform
-ldadim         0       0
-lifter         0       22
-lm                 sphinx-french/fr-small.lm.bin
-lmctl                  
-lmname                 
-logbase        1.0001      1.000100e+00
-logfn                  
-logspec        no      no
-lowerf         133.33334   1.300000e+02
-lpbeam         1e-40       1.000000e-40
-lponlybeam     7e-29       7.000000e-29
-lw         6.5     6.500000e+00
-maxhmmpf       30000       30000
-maxwpf         -1      -1
-mdef                   sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/mdef
-mean                   sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/means
-mfclogdir              
-min_endfr      0       0
-mixw                   sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/mixture_weights
-mixwfloor      0.0000001   1.000000e-07
-mllr                   
-mmap           yes     yes
-ncep           13      13
-nfft           512     512
-nfilt          40      25
-nwpen          1.0     1.000000e+00
-pbeam          1e-48       1.000000e-48
-pip            1.0     1.000000e+00
-pl_beam        1e-10       1.000000e-10
-pl_pbeam       1e-10       1.000000e-10
-pl_pip         1.0     1.000000e+00
-pl_weight      3.0     3.000000e+00
-pl_window      5       5
-rawlogdir              
-remove_dc      no      no
-remove_noise       yes     yes
-remove_silence     yes     yes
-round_filters      yes     yes
-samprate       16000       1.600000e+04
-seed           -1      -1
-sendump                
-senlogdir              
-senmgau                
-silprob        0.005       5.000000e-03
-smoothspec     no      no
-svspec                 
-tmat                   sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/transition_matrices
-tmatfloor      0.0001      1.000000e-04
-topn           4       4
-topn_beam      0       0
-toprule                
-transform      legacy      dct
-unit_area      yes     yes
-upperf         6855.4976   6.800000e+03
-uw         1.0     1.000000e+00
-vad_postspeech     50      50
-vad_prespeech      20      20
-vad_startspeech    10      10
-vad_threshold      2.0     2.000000e+00
-var                    sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/variances
-varfloor       0.0001      1.000000e-04
-varnorm        no      no
-verbose        no      no
-warp_params                
-warp_type      inverse_linear  inverse_linear
-wbeam          7e-29       7.000000e-29
-wip            0.65        6.500000e-01
-wlen           0.025625    2.562500e-02

INFO: feat.c(715): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='current', VARNORM='no', AGC='none' INFO: cmn.c(143): mean[0]= 12.00, mean[1..12]= 0.0 INFO: acmod.c(154): Reading linear feature transformation from sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/feature_transform INFO: mdef.c(518): Reading model definition: sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/mdef INFO: bin_mdef.c(181): Allocating 101051 * 8 bytes (789 KiB) for CD tree INFO: tmat.c(206): Reading HMM transition probability matrices: sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/transition_matrices INFO: acmod.c(117): Attempting to use PTM computation module INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/means INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size:  INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  8x32 INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/variances INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size:  INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  8x32 INFO: ms_gauden.c(354): 0 variance values floored INFO: ptm_mgau.c(801): Number of codebooks exceeds 256: 2108 INFO: acmod.c(119): Attempting to use semi-continuous computation module INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/means INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size:  INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  8x32 INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/variances INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size:  INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  8x32 INFO: ms_gauden.c(354): 0 variance values floored INFO: acmod.c(121): Falling back to general multi-stream GMM computation INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/means INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size:  INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  8x32 INFO: ms_gauden.c(198): Reading mixture gaussian parameter: sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/variances INFO: ms_gauden.c(292): 2108 codebook, 1 feature, size:  INFO: ms_gauden.c(294):  8x32 INFO: ms_gauden.c(354): 0 variance values floored INFO: ms_senone.c(149): Reading senone mixture weights: sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/mixture_weights INFO: ms_senone.c(200): Truncating senone logs3(pdf) values by 10 bits INFO: ms_senone.c(207): Not transposing mixture weights in memory INFO: ms_senone.c(268): Read mixture weights for 2108 senones: 1 features x 8 codewords INFO: ms_senone.c(320): Mapping senones to individual codebooks INFO: ms_mgau.c(141): The value of topn: 4 INFO: phone_loop_search.c(114): State beam -225 Phone exit beam -225 Insertion penalty 0 INFO: dict.c(320): Allocating 109102 * 20 bytes (2130 KiB) for word entries INFO: dict.c(333): Reading main dictionary: sphinx-french/fr.dict INFO: dict.c(213): Allocated 1018 KiB for strings, 1375 KiB for phones INFO: dict.c(336): 105003 words read INFO: dict.c(358): Reading filler dictionary: sphinx-french/cmusphinx-fr-5.2/noisedict INFO: dict.c(213): Allocated 0 KiB for strings, 0 KiB for phones INFO: dict.c(361): 3 words read INFO: dict2pid.c(396): Building PID tables for dictionary INFO: dict2pid.c(406): Allocating 36^3 * 2 bytes (91 KiB) for word-initial triphones INFO: dict2pid.c(132): Allocated 15696 bytes (15 KiB) for word-final triphones INFO: dict2pid.c(196): Allocated 15696 bytes (15 KiB) for single-phone word triphones INFO: ngram_model_trie.c(456): Trying to read LM in trie binary format INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(99): 742 unique initial diphones INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(148): 0 root, 0 non-root channels, 132 single-phone words INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(186): Creating search tree INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(192): before: 0 root, 0 non-root channels, 132 single-phone words INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(326): after: max nonroot chan increased to 122777 INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(339): after: 733 root, 122649 non-root channels, 124 single-phone words INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(157): fwdflat: min_ef_width = 4, max_sf_win = 25 INFO: continuous.c(305): pocketsphinx_continuous COMPILED ON: May 22 2016, AT: 22:01:16

READY.... Listening... INFO: ngram_search.c(459): Resized backpointer table to 10000 entries INFO: ngram_search.c(467): Resized score stack to 200000 entries INFO: ngram_search.c(459): Resized backpointer table to 20000 entries INFO: ngram_search.c(467): Resized score stack to 400000 entries INFO: ngram_search.c(459): Resized backpointer table to 40000 entries INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(952): cand_sf[] increased to 64 entries Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal) INFO: cmn_prior.c(131): cmn_prior_update: from <  8.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 
0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 > INFO: cmn_prior.c(149): cmn_prior_update: to   < 20.14  5.01  9.56  2.81
-0.91  5.44  1.24 -1.23 -0.46 -1.34 -0.56  1.64  3.27 > INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1553):    31150 words recognized (98/fr) INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1555):   504243 senones evaluated (1591/fr) INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1559):  6306963 channels searched (19895/fr), 208020 1st, 615812 last INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1562):    61696 words for which last channels evaluated (194/fr) INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1564):   787418 candidate words for entering last phone (2483/fr) INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1567): fwdtree 21.23 CPU 6.698 xRT INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1570): fwdtree 29.45 wall 9.290 xRT INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(302): Utterance vocabulary contains 1051 words INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(948):    16647 words recognized (53/fr) INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(950):   355200 senones evaluated (1121/fr) INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(952):  1666450 channels searched (5256/fr) INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(954):   142520 words searched (449/fr) INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(957):    71616 word transitions (225/fr) INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(960): fwdflat 6.84 CPU 2.158 xRT INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(963): fwdflat 6.84 wall
2.159 xRT INFO: ngram_search.c(1200): </s> not found in last frame, using membres.315 instead INFO: ngram_search.c(1253): lattice start node <s>.0 end node membres.233 INFO: ngram_search.c(1279): Eliminated 201 nodes before end node INFO: ngram_search.c(1384): Lattice has 1802 nodes, 40836 links INFO: ps_lattice.c(1380): Bestpath score: -10518 INFO: ps_lattice.c(1384): Normalizer P(O) = alpha(membres:233:315) =
-772446 INFO: ps_lattice.c(1441): Joint P(O,S) = -795829 P(S|O) = -23383 INFO: ngram_search.c(875): bestpath 3.10 CPU 0.982 xRT INFO: ngram_search.c(878): bestpath 3.10 wall 0.982 xRT on vous vous vous membres
```

But It ends up with this feedback on my speaker (I don't put the whole log because of character limitation):

```
INFO: continuous.c(252): Ready....                                              
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)                              
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)                              
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)                              
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)                              
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)                              
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)                              
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)                              
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)                              
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)                              
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)                              
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)                              
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)                              
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)                              
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)                              
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)                              
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)                              
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)                              
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)                              
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)                              
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)                              
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)                              
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)                              
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)                              
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)                              
Input overrun, read calls are too rare (non-fatal)
```

(For the note, I use pocketsphinx french model)

My question is: do you have any idea why ? It is probably not a problem of  power processing, since it works on raspberry.

Answer (score 0):

The message says that processing is too slow.

You need to run decoding from a file on your device, not from a microphone and tune the speed first. Speed must be faster than realtime in the logs.

You need to use smaller models or optimize the speed with beams/other parameters as described [in the wiki](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/pocketsphinxhandhelds/)

Comment: OK but what I don't understand is that despite my two devices having similar hardwares decoding from microphone works on the raspberry but not on the speaker. So I'd like to have an idea about where the difference might be. For practical reason I don't use the same microphone on both devices, can the difference in the mic be the origin of the problem ?

Comment: Yes, the driver of the microphone can consume a lot of resources. You have to decode from the file first to compare speed like I wrote you.